# How to submit Apache Airflow EMR job on EC2?

Tags: python, airflow, amazon-emr

I am trying to submit EMR jobs. EMR on EC2. I am suing the code given by Airflow. Installed Airflow with Docker as recommended by Apache Airflow.

> 

This is given in automatic steps
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-amazon/2.2.0/_modules/airflow/providers/amazon/aws/example_dags/example_emr_job_flow_automatic_steps.html

from datetime import timedelta
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.operators.emr_create_job_flow import EmrCreateJobFlowOperator
from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.sensors.emr_job_flow import EmrJobFlowSensor
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago

SPARK_STEPS = [
{
'Name': 'calculate_pi',
'ActionOnFailure': 'CONTINUE',
'HadoopJarStep': {
'Jar': 'command-runner.jar',
'Args': ['/usr/lib/spark/bin/run-example', 'SparkPi', '10'],
},
}
]

JOB_FLOW_OVERRIDES = {
'Name': 'PiCalc',
'ReleaseLabel': 'emr-5.29.0',
'Instances': {
'InstanceGroups': [
{
'Name': 'Master node',
'Market': 'SPOT',
'InstanceRole': 'MASTER',
'InstanceType': 'm1.medium',
'InstanceCount': 1,
}
],
'KeepJobFlowAliveWhenNoSteps': False,
'TerminationProtected': False,
},
'Steps': SPARK_STEPS,
'JobFlowRole': 'EMR_EC2_DefaultRole',
'ServiceRole': 'EMR_DefaultRole',
}

with DAG(
dag_id='emr_job_flow_automatic_steps_dag',
default_args={
'owner': 'airflow',
'depends_on_past': False,
'email': ['airflow@example.com'],
'email_on_failure': False,
'email_on_retry': False,
},
dagrun_timeout=timedelta(hours=2),
start_date=days_ago(2),
schedule_interval='0 3 * * *',
tags=['example'],
) as dag:

```
# [START howto_operator_emr_automatic_steps_tasks]
job_flow_creator = EmrCreateJobFlowOperator(
    task_id='create_job_flow',
    job_flow_overrides=JOB_FLOW_OVERRIDES,
    aws_conn_id='aws_default',
    emr_conn_id='emr_default',
)

job_sensor = EmrJobFlowSensor(
    task_id='check_job_flow',
    job_flow_id=job_flow_creator.output,
    aws_conn_id='aws_default',
)
# [END howto_operator_emr_automatic_steps_tasks]

# Task dependency created via `XComArgs`:
#   job_flow_creator >> job_sensor
```

###########################################
Issues are:#

1. from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.operators.emr_create_job_flow import EmrCreateJobFlowOperator 
   from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.sensors.emr_job_flow import EmrJobFlowSensor

give error saying cannot import module though amazon providers is installed in my scheduler container. They can be imported using (given in manual steps)

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-amazon/7.4.1/_modules/tests/system/providers/amazon/aws/example_emr.html

from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.operators.emr import (
EmrAddStepsOperator,
EmrCreateJobFlowOperator,
EmrModifyClusterOperator,
EmrTerminateJobFlowOperator,
) 
from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.sensors.emr import EmrJobFlowSensor

2. While submitting job ['Args': ['/usr/lib/spark/bin/run-example', 'SparkPi', '10'],] gives error saying \

"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/usr/lib/spark/bin/run-example" (in directory "."): error=2, No such file or directory "

What is my issues here? Expecting some help. Thanks